# Isotopes and their percentage existence in atmosphere

Tags: isotope

When we talk about percentages of isotopes of an element in the atmosphere, is it percent by mass or volume or weight or something else?

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:** it's the percent by number of particles.

**Longer answer:** It's the proportion of particles of a particular mass for that element.  To chemists, a *per particle* basis is also commonly referred to as a *per mol* basis or a *molar* basis.

A way that it can be measured is by [mass spectrometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry) - you pass the atoms through the apparatus which shows the mass to charge ratio. E.g. if you could pass $\ce{Cl}$ molecules, you'd see 2 peaks in the resulting graph - one is at 35 and the other at 37 marks which shows the mass/charge. First peak would be about 3 times larger (thus there were 3 times more particles). Thus chlorine would be about 75% isotope 35 and 25% isotope 37. So while this approach measures mass of each isotope, it also determines the relative *molar* amounts of each isotope.